# Android: How to get object attribute from List<Class> using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, list, retrofit

much please, help me with that issue. I want to get some data from JSON object via REST API.

Here is a demonstration of json:

```
{
"itemList": [
    {
        "name": "AF1_AC",
        "value": false,
        "awid": "1",
        "sys": {
            "cts": "2018-07-16T14:51:34.166Z",
            "mts": "2018-07-16T17:49:40.206Z",
            "rev": 775
        },
        "id": "5b4cb0f66a4c333860d64d79"
    },
    {
        "name": "ST1_RE",
        "value": 27.11,
        "awid": "1",
        "sys": {
            "cts": "2018-07-15T14:53:05.228Z",
            "mts": "2018-07-16T17:49:40.320Z",
            "rev": 4124
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface FarmAPI {

String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:6221/";

@GET("smartfarm/0-1/listFarmObjectValue") Call<ItemList> getItemList();

class Factory {
    private static FarmAPI service;

    public static FarmAPI getInstance() {
        if (service == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
                    addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client).build();
            service = retrofit.create(FarmAPI.class);
            return service;
        } else {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is Class generated by jsonschema2pojo:

```
public class ListFarmObjectValue {

@SerializedName("itemList")
@Expose
private List<ItemList> itemList = null;

public List<ItemList> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(List<ItemList> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}
```

}

and the second:

```
public class ItemList {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private double value;
@SerializedName("awid")
@Expose
private String awid;

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getAwid() {
    return awid;
}

public void setAwid(String awid) {
    this.awid = awid;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Now I want to get value from object, where name = ST1_RE and set value to specific TextView. In method onCreate:

```
FarmAPI.Factory.getInstance().getItemList().enqueue(new Callback<ItemList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ItemList> call, Response<ItemList> response) {
            if (response.body().getName().equals("ST1_RE")) {
                realTemperature.setText(response.body().getValue() + "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ItemList> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

but it does not work :( 
Can you please show me how can I do that exactly on this situation? Or maybe without generating classes via jsonschema2pojo if it is better...? I saw some examples but its new category for me and I dont understand it. And also I dont want to change FarmAPI interface, because I use that in other situations.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Change the expected type for the API call

`@GET("smartfarm/0-1/listFarmObjectValue") Call<ItemList> getItemList();`

to

`@GET("smartfarm/0-1/listFarmObjectValue") Call< ListFarmObjectValue > getItemList();`

2)Iterate through the list of ItemList objects to find the one whose name is 'ST1_RE'

`FarmAPI.Factory.getInstance().getItemList().enqueue(new Callback<ListFarmObjectValue>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListFarmObjectValue> call, Response<ListFarmObjectValue> response) {
            ListFarmObjectValue value = response.body();
            for(ItemList item : value.getItemList()){
                 if (item.getName().equals("ST1_RE")) {
                      realTemperature.setText(response.body().getValue() + "");
                      break;
                  }
             }
        }
    });`

Edit:
I just saw your message that you don't want to change the API call. In that case, just create a new method in the same class with the new return type as I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much for fast reply, but it does not work. 
I changed realTemperature.setText(response.body().getValue() + "");
to 
realTemperature.setText(item.getValue() + ""); 
but TextView does not change. But in console, there are correct data.

Maybe there is problem in generated class. Could you please show me how can I do that with my own created classes for this json? Thank you!

Comment: Put a Debug point inside the onRespose() method and see if it's going through all the case as expected. Also, See if it's not a UI issue like TextView not visible for some reasons. Set hardcoded text to the text view to confirm all is good from UI.

Comment: It jumps into onFailure method. I see exception: 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a double but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 40 path $.itemList[0].value
It seems that I cant have boolean and also double. But in json there are 2 types of value - boolean and double. Please, is there some way how to do that? Thank you

Comment: You can make the 'value' type as 'Object' instead of 'double' and can cast it appropriately after checking the type using 'instanceof'. But you can only cast to Double or Boolean, not primitive double/boolean.